# Flutter Postman API

Tags: flutter, api, rest, postman

I am using postman API for login flutter. I want that it will give 'Invalid credentials" when the wrong user tries to log in. The problem is: it is logging in when the wrong user tries to log in... what am I mistaking. I couldn't figure it out. Can some help me, please!

[calling API function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZV4m7.png)

[Login Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj0SV.png)

Comment: Are you sure the server is not returning 200?